# Creating a Contact list hash table with a certain hash function algorithm , table size of 1009 elements and linear probing of interval (1)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a hash table for a contact list with a certain hash function algorithm and table size of 1009 using python.

It was fine with everything while testing but the indexing of the elements wasn't right as the algorithm should give me.
Here is the complete source code for Examination:

```py
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone

    def calc_hash(key, table_size):
        l = len(key)
        hash_value = 0

        for i in range(l):
            hash_value += ord(key[i])
            hash_value += (hash_value << 10)
            hash_value ^= (hash_value >> 6)

        hash_value += (hash_value << 3)
        hash_value ^= (hash_value >> 11)
        hash_value += (hash_value << 15)

        if hash_value > 0:
            return hash_value % table_size
        else:
            return -hash_value % table_size

class HashTable:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.table = [None] * size

    def hash_function(self, key):
        return Contact.calc_hash(key, self.size)

    def linear_probing(self, index, attempt):
        return (index + attempt) % self.size

    def insert(self, contact):
        key = contact.name
        index = self.hash_function(key)
        attempt = 0

        while self.table[index] is not None:
            attempt += 1
            index = self.linear_probing(index, attempt)

        contact.key = index  # Store the calculated key in the contact object
        self.table[index] = contact

    def search(self, key):
        index = self.hash_function(key)
        attempt = 0

        while self.table[index] is not None:
            if self.table[index].name == key:
                return self.table[index]

            attempt += 1
            index = self.linear_probing(index, attempt)

        return None

    def display(self):
        for i, contact in enumerate(self.table):
            if contact is not None:
                print(f"Index {i}: {contact.name} - {contact.phone}")
            else:
                print(f"Index {i}: Empty")

# Example usage:
contact_list = [
    Contact("Sam Doe", "+1-555-1234"),
    Contact("John Smith", "+1-555-8976"),
    Contact("Lisa Smith", "+1-555-5030")
]

hash_table = HashTable(1009)

for contact in contact_list:
    hash_table.insert(contact)

hash_table.display()

# Searching for a contact
search_key = "Sam Doe"
result = hash_table.search(search_key)

if result:
    print(f"Contact found: {result.name} - {result.phone} and his position is {result.key}")
else:
    print(f"Contact not found for key: {search_key}")
```

In this example here , the index of ("John Smith") should be 343 , the index of ("Sam doe") should be 681 and the index of ("Lisa Smith") should 950 , that is the correct indexes if the hash mapping function algorithm worked fine , but the idexes aren't correct here , it's giving me ("John Smith") an index of 142 , ("Sam Doe") an index of 579 and ("Lisa Smith") an index of 566.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: make `calc_hash` `@staticmethod`

Comment: what is your source for this hash calculation, how can your hash value be negative

Comment: @mkrieger1 how to make it correct becayse the indexes aren't correct here

Comment: @rioV8 tried it before you even told me , it didn't change a thing about the results

Comment: it's a given hash function rules that were given to me , just putting an assumption so nevermind that

Comment: was the hash  function code given in Python, in equations, pseudo code,.....

Comment: no , it was given to me in java code and I transcripted it to python code , that is the java code by the way :
public static long calc_hash( String key, int table_size) {
 int i, l = key.length();
 long hash = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
 hash += Character.getNumericValue(key.charAt(i));
 hash += (hash << 10);
 hash ^= (hash >> 6);
 }
 hash += (hash << 3);
 hash ^= (hash >> 11);
 hash += (hash << 15);
 
 if ( hash > 0) return hash % table_size;
 else return -hash % table_size;
}